# выполняется лишь последняя команда из очереди

Tags: php, mysql

Есть код

```
<?phpif ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
require 'connect_k.php';
createMessage();}function createMessage(){
global $connect;    
$email = $_POST["email"];
$query="INSERT INTO final(email,name,size,quantity,price)SELECT email,name,size,quantity,price FROM items_cart WHERE email like ('$email');";
$query_del="DELETE FROM items_cart WHERE email like ('$email');";
mysqli_query ($connect,$query,$query_del)or die (mysqli_error($connect));
mysqli_close($connect);
```

Почему то выполняется лишь последняя команда либо `$query`, либо `$query_del`, в зависимости что стоит позже, в данном случае `$query_del`. Как правильно прописать чтобы работало всё.

Comment: `mysqli_query()` не может выполнить несколько команд в одном вызове, у неё попросту не такая сигнатура. Она расчитана на след. аргументы: ссылка, запрос, result_mode, и все. С чего Вы взял, что данный вызов допустим.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам требуется дважды вызвать `mysqli_query()`. Например так:

```
mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
mysqli_query($connect, $query_del) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
```